# Array argument to rules action

Tags: rules

I am building a Rules action that needs to take an array argument, that I would populate using a PHP script on the action UI.

Let's say the action is called TranslateMessage, with arg1 = text, arg2 = array

How to declare arg2 so that it shows up as a text area with PHP input in the Rules UI, and send the array (that I create in the PHP area) as an argument to the action function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to serialize that array or json decode it, than it can easily be passed as a string.